# why am I getting HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl with java.protocol.handler.pkgs set to org.apache.catalina.webresources?

Tags: java, https, tomcat9, catalina

My Tomcat 9 + Java 11 application has the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` property set to `org.apache.catalina.webresources`.

A previous developer has put the following line:

`HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(protocol + hostname + path).openConnection();`

and this results in the following error:

`class com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to class javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`.

I've looked at previous questions around this error but they seem to revolve around some other value for `java.protocol.handler.pkgs`.

I have checked the values being used to build the URL; `protocol` is definitely set to "https://", and `hostname` and `path` are set to reasonable values.

1. What do I need to reconfigure to fix this?
2. Why am I getting that OldImpl class invoked in the first place?